# Ordering input tags in XML::Simple using Perl while printing the output in XML format

Tags: perl, xml-simple

How to order the input tags in Perl code using XML::Simple module for printing the output in XML format in specified order..
i have tried this

```
    use XML::Simple;
    use Data::Dumper;
    open (FH,"> xml4.txt") || die (); 
    # create array
    @arr = {
        'name'=>['Cisco102'],
        'SSIDConfig'=>[
                {'SSID'=> [{'name'=>'Cisco102'}]}],
        'connectionType'=>['ESS'],
        'connectionMode'=>['auto'],
        'autoSwitch'=>['false'],
        'MSM'=>[{'security' =>[ { 'authEncryption' =>[{'authentication' => 'open',
                        'encryption' => 'WEP',
                          'useOneX' => 'false'
                                        }],
                      'sharedKey' =>[ {
                                     'keyType' => 'networkKey',
                                     'protected' => 'false',
                                     'keyMaterial' => '1234567890'
                                   }]}]}]};
# create object
$xml = new XML::Simple(NoAttr=>1,RootName=>'WLAN Profile');
# convert Perl array ref into XML document
 $data = $xml->XMLout(@arr,xmldecl => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>');
# access XML data
print FH $data;
```

but i am not getting the order which i required..i need the order ->name,SSID Config,Connectionmode,connectiontype,autoswitch,MSM .help me

Comment: You can't, that's not how XML::Simple works. It doesn't keep the order of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you want 2 things for your XML:

- no attributes, hence the `NoAttr` option in the XML::Simple object creation
- the order of the elements should be as specified

I am not sure why you don't want attributes in your XML, and why the data structure you use to create it has them. You may want to look into that. In any case XML::Simple gives you this feature.

For the second part, XML::Simple doesn't keep the order, and I have found no way to make it do it, so you will need something else.

For a quick and dirty solution, A little bit of XML::Twig in there would do:

```
# instead of the print FH $data; line

my $twig= XML::Twig->new( )->parse( $data);
$twig->root->set_content( map { $dtwig->root->first_child( $_) } (qw( name SSIDConfig connectionMode connectionType autoSwitch MSM)) );

$twig->print( \*FH);
```

A couple more comments:

- you can't use 'WLAN Profile` as the root tag, XML names cannot include spaces
- it is generally considered polite, when you ask a question about Perl, to show code that uses strict and warnings
- the proper way to open the output file would be `my $out_file= xml4.txt; open ( my $fh,'>', $out_file) or die "cannot create $out_file: $!";` (or use `autodie` instead of the `die`), using 3 args open and lexical filehandles is a good habit (this message from the 3-arg open police department ;--)

Comment: Thank you mirod you have helped me a lott..thanks for your comments also..i want to order the elements of sharedkey also (keyType protected keyMaterial) how do i do that ?? and Can i indent the output using XML::Twig??

Comment: @user968434 sure, pass `pretty_print => 'indented'` either to `new` or to `print`: `$data->print(pretty_print => 'indented', \*FH);`Also, I have fixed the code, it should be `autoSwitch` (uper case S) and not `autoswitch` as I had written, which screwed up the output

Comment: Thanks,the output is indented now..:) but the order of attributes of sharedKey is still not fixed,I need it as keyType,protected,keyMaterial while the order Iam getting them is keyMaterial, keyType, protected.How do I fix it?

Comment: and one more thing i need to add <WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"> in the second line of XML file and not just <WLANProfile>.Help me with these two things

Comment: i used $twig->set_att('WLANProfile'=>'xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"'); then its giving an error "Can't locate object method "set_att" via package "XML::Twig" at new.pl line xx".wat to do?? and tell me how to order the attributes of sharedKey, need it as keyType,protected,keyMaterial while the order Iam getting them is keyMaterial, keyType, protected.How to do it?

Comment: really, it would be easier for the both of us if you read the docs of the module. See http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/twig_dev.html#METHODS_XML_Twig_Elt_set_att

Comment: Thanks mirod for the help..got the file in required format,i did this work in Linux.How to install XML::Twig in windows XP?i tried ppm and also tried manually with Nmake but i got ERROR "NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\Documents'
Stop."

Comment: if you use Activestate Perl there should be a PPM, if you use Strawberry Perl you can use CPAN (and probably cpanm, which would be even easier). If everything else fails, you can copy Twig.pm somewhere where Perl looks for modules (`perl -l -E'print join "\n", @INC'` gives you the base list, then create an XML directory under one of those and copy Twig.pm there. But really, learning how to install modules properly would pay for itself in no time.

Comment: i tried the same way before it was giving " 'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable programme or batch file' "..i am using Activestate Perl there is a PPM but it doesn't have XML::Twig in it.

Comment: I see XML::Twig in the list of supported PPMs: http://ppm4.activestate.com/idx/X.html so it should be there. A quick Google search also shows http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/dist/XML-Twig which lists many PPMs for the module

Answer (score 2):

Hashes aren't ordered. You could try using a [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aIxHash) (which looks like a hash, but maintains insertion order) instead of a normal hash. If that doesn't work, XML::Simple won't be of use to you.

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried, a long time ago to get the 2 modules to play nice with each other, but it didn't quite work, XML::Simple copies hashes in too many places for it to be simple.